# Objective-C: Mutating a property in implementation file

Tags: objective-c

```
PeopleClass.h

@interface PeopleClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *people;
@end
```

I would like to make the `people` property above mutable (`NSMutableDictionary`) only in .m file.  So when I mutate `people` dictionary, the changes are reflected in the interfaces `NSDictionary`

I have tried making an iVar like below, but that didn't work.

```
PeopleClass.m

@interface PeopleClass ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *people;   
}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you need to provide your own instance variable and your own setter and getter methods. Below is the basic setup:

PeopleClass.h

```
@interface PeopleClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *people;
@end
```

PeopleClass.m

```
@implementation PeopleClass {
    NSMutableDictionary *_people;
}

- (NSDictionary *)people {
    return [_people copy]; // or just return _people
}

- (void)setPeople:(NSDictionary *)people {
    _people = [people mutableCopy];
}
```

The use of `copy` in the getter method is optional. It depends on how you want the result to be handled.

It would probably also make sense to change the property to be `copy` instead of `strong` since the implementation of the setter and getter really honor `copy` and not just `strong`.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to return a mutable dictionary as an immutable reference to clients.   First, if you later mutate, the code consuming that reference is likely going to break as it is written with the assumption that it can't mutate.   Secondly, some clients of said code may have a bug that mutates the contents, leading to your code breaking (this happened in Cocoa).

Instead:

```
@interface PeopleClass : NSObject
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *people;
@end
```

In your .m:

```
@interface PeopleClass()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *mutablePeople;

- ... init ...
{
    ....
    _mutablePeople = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    ....
}

- (NSDictionary *) people
{
    return [_mutablePeople copy];
}
```

If the copying is *really* a performance problem (determined by instrumentation & analysis), then you can keep the copy around and invalidate/replace it whenever the backing store is mutated.